# How to show informations with triggering the show/close button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the progress of learning React. I want to show countries' information via the toggleable button. But I have some problem with that.
There is an input box that is triggered by entering letters. I send HTTP Get Request depends on this input and the response is being filtered. The value which is filtered appears on the screen.

[image]

Ass you see, I just want the country name and button to appear. After that, when I press the button, only information about that country should come.

My code:

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import Countries from './components/Countries'
const App = () => { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Countries />     
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

**Countries.js**

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import ShowSection from './ShowSection'
import axios from 'axios'

const Countries = (props) => {
    
    const [search,setSearch] = useState('')  
    const [countries,setCountries] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=> {
      axios
        .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Burda")
          const responseCountries = response.data
          const filter = responseCountries.filter(el =>
                 el.name.toLowerCase()
                 .indexOf(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1)
          setCountries(filter)
        })
    },[search])

    const handleInput = (event) => {
       setSearch(event.target.value)
       console.log(countries)
    }


    return(
       <div>
         find countries <input onChange={handleInput}/>
         <div>
           <ShowSection  list={countries}/>
          
         </div>
       </div>
    )
}

export default Countries
```

**ShowSection.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import InfoSection from './InfoSection'

const ShowSection = (props) => {
    const {list} = props
    
    var id = 0;

    if(list.length === 1){
      return(
        <div>
          {
            list.map((item,index) =>
               <div>
                  <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                  <p>capital {item.capital}</p>
                  <p>population {item.population}</p>
                  <h3>languages</h3>
                  <ul>
                    {item.languages.map(m =>
                      <li key={index.toString()}>{m.name}</li>)}
                  </ul>
                  <img alt="Flag" src={item.flag} width="150px" height="150px"/>
              </div>
              )
          }
          
        </div>
      )
    }
    else if(list.length <= 10){
      return(
        list.map((item,i) =>
        
        <div>
           <InfoSection key={item.id} item={item} num={++id}/>
       </div>
       )
      )
      
    }
    else{
      return(
        <div>Nothing to rendered</div>
      )
    }
    
  }

export default ShowSection
```

**InfoSection.js**

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const InfoSection = (props) => {
    const {item} = props
    const [toggle,setToggle] = useState(false)

    return(
        <div>
          {item.name}
          <button onClick={() =>setToggle(!toggle)}>
            {toggle ? 'Cancel' : 'Show'}
          </button>
          <p>capital {item.capital}</p>
          <p>population {item.population}</p>
          <h3>languages</h3>
          <ul>
            {item.languages.map(m =>
              <li key={item.callingCodes}>{m.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <img alt="Flag" src={item.flag} width="150px" height="150px"/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default InfoSection
```

Comment: Seems like you just missing `{toggle && <><p>capital {item.capital}</p> /* etc… */</>}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @GG mentioned in the comments, you can use conditional rendering to display the details of the country when `toggle` is `true`/`false`.

Like this

```js
return(
    <div>
      {item.name}
      <button onClick={() =>setToggle(!toggle)}>
          {toggle ? 'Cancel' : 'Show'}
      </button>
      {toggle &&
        <>
          <p>capital {item.capital}</p>
          <p>population {item.population}</p>
          <h3>languages</h3>
        
          <ul>
            {item.languages.map(m =>
              <li key={item.callingCodes}>{m.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <img alt="Flag" src={item.flag} width="150px" height="150px"/>
        </>
       }
    </div>
)
```